# Deselect checkbox when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm doing this simple hamburger menu in pure HTML and CSS (from [CodeMyUI](https://codemyui.com/hamburger-menu-full-screen-navigation-menu-pure-css/)), and I would like it to auto close when a link is clicked. Using `vue` with `router-links` the page isn't reloaded.

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
    <label for="menu"></label>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <router-link to="/" class="mainlink">{{ $t("message.navFront") }}</router-link>
      <router-link to="/about" class="mainlink">{{ $t("message.navAbout") }}</router-link>
      <router-link to="/portfolio" class="mainlink">{{ $t("message.navPort") }}</router-link>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Comment: Show us your code, what are trying to do to achive this **StackOverflow** isn't a _how to_ site...

Comment: @Matheus Cuba, Follow the link provided by Thomas Alexander Woolff, and there is a framed CodePen where you can see his source code.

Comment: @Davide: the OP must provide: the [mcve] required to reproduce the described problem; an explanation of what happens when that code is run (the problem itself); an explanation of what s/he wants, or expects, to happen. Linking to an external resource (whether CodePen, JS Fiddle, or their own website) and expecting us to go there to see the code is not acceptable (it's a nice bonus in many cases, but it's not a replacement for posting the required code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using v-model to bind the value?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" v-model="checkboxValue />
<router-link to="/" class="mainlink" @click.native="uncheck">{{ $t("message.navFront") }}</router-link>
```

Then you should at the checkboxValue to the data() and the uncheck method to methods.

```
data() {
 return {
    checkboxValue: false,
}; },

methods:{
 uncheck(){
  this.checkboxValue = false;
}}
```

With this you should be able to deselect the checkbox once you click on the links.

Edit: So apparently the routes-link element doesn't support @click, but it might support @click.native (or v-on:click.native)

Comment: I tried your solution, its like the vue instance isn't updating. Im running a vue-cli install, could that be the problem?. The script looks like this:

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      checkboxValue: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uncheck () {
      this.checkboxValue = false
    }
  }
}
</script>

Comment: Its when the @click="uncheck" is on the router-link that it doesnt work! I works like a charm when its on a normal a href tag.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAlexanderWoolff I've seen that the router-link doesn't support the click event https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/800 but it seems that by using v-on:click.native it could work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to uncheck  `<input type="checkbox" id="menu" />` when a click happens on a link within the menu.

with a nice vue event explained like here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

maybe somehow like this:

**template**

```
<router-link to="/" class="mainlink" v-on:click="uncheck"> {{ $t("message.navFront") }} </router-link>
```

**js**

```
methods: {
    uncheck: function (event) {
      document.getElementById("menu").checked = false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: In vue.js I think the js should be: 
methods: {
  uncheck: function(event) {
    document.getElementById("menu").checked = false;
  }
}

But that gives me an error